# Find Least Squares Problem Given Alternative Normal Equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, least-squares

In my revision I came across this problem:

[image]

How does the fact that $M = C^T C$ give the final result? For instance, why is $\hat x_M = \arg\min_x \Vert M^{-1}(Ax - b)\Vert_2$ not a valid result for the least squares problem? In general, how can we take some normal equation and obtain a corresponding least-squares problem?